# LINQ: How to skip one then take the rest of a sequence

Tags: c#, linq, list, loops, skip

i would like to iterate over the items of a `List<T>`, except the first, preserving the order. Is there an elegant way to do it with LINQ using a statement like:

> foreach (var item in list.Skip(1).**TakeTheRest()**)
>   {....

I played around with `TakeWhile` , but was not successful. Probably there is also another, simple way of doing it?

Comment: Hmmm, wasn't this question asked yesterday?

Comment: Which question? Would you mind providing the link?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

From the documentation for [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx):

> Bypasses a specified number of elements in a sequence and then returns the remaining elements.

So you just need this:

```
foreach (var item in list.Skip(1))
```

Comment: Thanks man (banging my head against the keyboard for not seeing this obvious solution...)

Comment: And if you wanted to take a certain number of values, you would simply do `foreach (var item in list.Skip(1).Take(count))`

Answer (score 10):

Just do:

```
foreach (var item in input.Skip(1))
```

There's some more info on [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/return-or-skip-elements-in-a-sequence).

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't it be...

```
foreach (var in list.Skip(1).AsEnumerable())
```

Comment: The AsEnumerable is not needed, as Mark's solution works perfectly.

Comment: Skip(1)  by default makes it Enumerable