# skip ahead in a foreach loop c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach

if I have a foreach loop that takes a whole bunch of addresses and loops through them, is there a way I could skip the first 500 entries,

something like:

```
foreach(var row in addresses)
{
  string strAddr = row.ADDRESS + "," + row.CITY + "," + row.ST;
  System.Threading.Thread.Skip(500)
}
```

I know skip doesn't exist but is there anything I can use that would do the same thing?

Comment: Use `Enumerable.Skip` like `foreach(var row in addresses.Skip(500))`

Comment: Do you want to skip ONLY the first 500 entries or take every 500th item?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ: How to skip one then take the rest of a sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431744/linq-how-to-skip-one-then-take-the-rest-of-a-sequence)

Comment: Note: `.Skip(int value)` is available on `IEnumerable<T>` when you add `using System.Linq`.

Comment: only the first 500 need to be skipped

Comment: I believe that you want to skip after certain conditions? and that's the reason why you have your skip in the pseudo code on the last line of the loop right? In that case, use a for loop instead of foreach and increase the loop counter variable with 500. In other words, what is the reason that you want to skip? is it to speed up? if so, you can also use the parralel for loop.

Comment: Then the answer from @TimSchmelter is what you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) with a meaningful name:

```
foreach(var row in addresses.Skip(500))
{
    // ...
}
```

You need to add `using System.Linq;` since it's a LINQ extension method.

If the type of `addresses` doesn't implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface you could use `Cast<T>`. For example (presuming the type is `Address`):

```
foreach(var row in addresses.Cast<Address>().Skip(500))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: However, since he is using `foreach(var row` and row is apparently not of type `object`, we can assume that addresses implements `IEnumerable<Address>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method:

```
foreach(var row in addresses.Skip(500))
{
    string strAddr = row.ADDRESS + "," + row.CITY + "," + row.ST;
}
```

Or, if `addresses` is just an array or list:

```
for (int i = 500 ; i < addresses.Count ; i++) // assuming addresses is a List<T>
{
    var row = addresses[i];
    string strAddr = row.ADDRESS + "," + row.CITY + "," + row.ST;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Enumerator interface directly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var enumerator = addresses.GetEnumerator();
for (var i = 0; i < 300 && enumerator.MoveNext(); i++);
```

Answer (score 1):

A feasible and fast solution would be to use LINQ [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/vstudio/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to iterate over a subset of the collection starting from the 500th element of the collection.

```
foreach (var row in addresses.Skip(500))
{
   // do your stuff...
}
```